# How to Insert long html, images and long String in Oracle (long data) as a Single Column?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to insert a long data into one column, that data containing html, images binary data and string. What data type need to use to insert the data into column [ big data].
I am written a query to insert into oracle database but at the time of insertion Oracle says
ORA-01704: string literal too long. I am inserting more than 1mb data into DB ( combination of text,html and binarydata). Any suggestions with example please.

Answer (score 1):

Use CLOB for long character data or BLOB for binary data.

Comment: thanks Jakub, My application has to read the data contain html , images and string data from UI and to be inserted into database single column. I used clob but it is not working

Comment: what's the problem when you use CLOB type as a column?

Comment: ORA-01704: string literal too long. Error when i am running my java application

Comment: How do you insert your data? If you use PreparedStatement make sure that you use setClob function not setString.

Answer (score 0):

Could BLOB/ CLOB do the job?

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefblob.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html

I however havent used one of them so faar

Comment: See Jakub Hr answer i guess CLOB is what youre going for if binary and character data is mixed